# Help translating one verse of hand-written Koine Greek (I believe)

Tags: greek, translation-philosophy, new-testament

[image]I've added arrows to specify which is the line I'm interested in, but give you the context in case its necessary.

I appreciate this help!

Thank you. It comes from Manuscript 472 ("Miniscule 472"), shelved as Manuscript 1177 in Labeth palace.

This digital copy can be viewed at the following link, and scroll to page 184 (manuscript page 354):
[http://images.lambethpalacelibrary.org.uk/luna/servlet/detail/LPLIBLPL~17~17~177134~124172?page=44&qvq=lc:LPLIBLPL~17~17&mi=44&trs=220](http://images.lambethpalacelibrary.org.uk/luna/servlet/detail/LPLIBLPL%7E17%7E17%7E177134%7E124172?page=44&qvq=lc:LPLIBLPL%7E17%7E17&mi=44&trs=220)

Comment: What document is this ? Please supply a reference.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  You will need to provide more context here - where does this MSS come from?  What is it?

Comment: The handwriting appears to be high to late medieval; but further context is needed.

Comment: I appears to be a prescription! https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ALeKk00wBSRFIktLYTk4A2cobX3LVO_aLQ%3A1601031635765&source=hp&biw=1920&bih=969&ei=081tX4izK4aD5wKitanABA&q=unreadable+prescription&oq=corpses+in+a+ditch&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECCMQJzoCCAA6BQgAELEDOggIABCxAxCDAToGCAAQChAYUJwoWL9kYMNmaAJwAHgAgAFPiAHXCpIBAjIwmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWc&sclient=img&ved=0ahUKEwjI6K7Pk4TsAhWGwVkKHaJaCkgQ4dUDCAc&uact=5#imgrc=Mbo-ptaP4u06fM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like “ΗΝ ΔΕ ΕΓΓΥΣ ΤΟ ΠΑΣΧΑ Η ΕΟΡΤΗ ΤΩΝ ΙΟΥΔΑΙΩΝ” (based on [help I received elsewhere](https://www.ibiblio.org/bgreek/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5267&p=35335#p35335)), which I would roughly translate as, “and the Passover, the feast of the Jews, was near”. This appears to be John 6:4 (also based on surrounding context).